# how do I serialize\deserialize NSLocale correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, foundation, kiwi

I'm trying to implement the protocol `<NSCoding>` for one of my classes.
I've come across a problem while seralizing\deseralizing one of the property of this class. The property is of type: `NSLocale`.

Here a (Kiwi) test I wrote to understand the behaviour of `NSLocale` :

```
   NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
   NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:locale];
   NSLocale *locale2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

   NSLog(@"1) %@", [locale localeIdentifier]); //=> "en_US"
   NSLog(@"2) %@", [locale2 localeIdentifier]); //=> "en_US"
   [[locale should] equal:locale2]; //=>fail

   [[[NSLocale currentLocale] should] equal:[NSLocale currentLocale]]; //=> pass
```

The test fails. do you guys know why?

Comment: I thought `should equal` does pointer level equivalence with `==`.  How could you expect two objects from different sources to have the same address?

Comment: Sorry for the tangent but what are the `should` and `equal:` methods?

Comment: I guess they come from the Kiwi framework

Comment: @CodaFi What makes you think that? I think `equal` calls `isEqual` on objects, whereas `beIdenticalTo` compares pointers

Comment: yes. I did use kiwi and I think equal calls [object isEqual:object2]. I'll verify and I'll edit the question

Comment: confirmed. I looked into the source code of Kiwi and it indeed calls `isEqual` on objects.

Answer (score 3):

#### NOTE

As per CodaFi comments below, this appears to be an issue with the implementation of `NSLocale`.

`NSCoder` produces an `NSCFLocale` instance, whereas straight allocation returns an `NSLocale`.

Due to the fact that `NSLocale` and `NSCFLocale` perform different equality checks (the former appears to be using `CFEqual()`, the latter `isEqualToString:`) this leads to the incongruences exposed below.

---

#### ORIGINAL POST

This is not exactly an answer, since I don't know what's going on, but I couldn't fit this in a comment. Here's the odd results of some testing

If you "manually" declare an instance of `NSLocale` everything works as expected

```
NSLocale * l1 = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:l1];
NSLocale *l2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSLog(@"%i", [l1 isEqual:l2]); // => 1, aka YES
```

But if you declare `l1` as `[NSLocale currentLocale]`, things go wrong

```
NSLocale * l1 = [NSLocale currentLocale];    
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:l1];
NSLocale *l2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSLog(@"%i", [l1 isEqual:l2]); // => 0, aka NO
```

Frankly I am as baffled as you are.

---

Extra info:

Here's the result of another test

```
NSLocale * l1 = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSLocale * l3 = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:l1];
NSData *data1 = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:l3];
NSLocale *l2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSLocale *l4 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data1];

NSLog(@"\n%p\n%p", l1, l2);    // => 0x9849da0
NSLog(@"\n%p\n%p", l3, l4);    // => 0x9866770
NSLog(@"%i", [l1 isEqual:l2]); // => 0x9866770
NSLog(@"%i", [l3 isEqual:l4]); // => 0x9866770
```

Surprisingly enough, the instance returned after unarchiving `l1` is the same as `l3`!

Comment: From what I can see from the ASM in CoreFoundation, some poor Apple engineer decided to do string equivalence with `CFEqual()` instead of `isEqualToString:`.  Filing a radar.

Comment: on which string? localeIdentifier?

Comment: The problem is that NSLocale and NSCFLocale have two differing opinions on equivalence.  NSCoder happens to be making you an NSCFLocale, where straight allocation is making you an NSLocale.

Comment: I see. You may post a link to the radar, so that other people will refer to it when reading this question